# My computer stopped recognizing my DVD rom & DVD writer

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a Gateway w/Wasp motherboard. My dvd rom and dvd writer are no longer working. Neither appear in Device Manager. dvd rom is master on ide cable, and dvd writer is slave. I tried looking in bios setting for them but don`t know where to search once in there. I`m using windows xp sp3. Any suggestions how to get them working again? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, remove the affected filter drivers. To do this, follow these steps:
Click StartCollapse this imageExpand this image, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then click regedit in the Programs list.

Collapse this imageExpand this imageIf you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type your password, or click Continue. 
Locate, and then click the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Caution There can be many instances of the registry subkey that is mentioned in step 2. You must make sure that you are in the appropriate registry subkey before modifying the UpperFilters and the LowerFilters values. To verify that you are in the appropriate registry subkey, make sure that the Default data value is DVD/CD-ROM and the Class data value is CDROM.
In the right pane, if you have UpperFilters, right-click UpperFilters, and then click Delete. 
Click Yes to confirm the removal of the UpperFilters registry entry.
In the right pane, if you have LowerFilters, right-click LowerFilters, and then click Delete. 
Click Yes to confirm the removal of the LowerFilters registry entry.
Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Ends up I disconnected the IDE (PATA) cable from the motherboard socket and reconnected it and it worked. Simple fix. Would be nice if all compuer issues were this easy to fix. :)